# mysql value to javascript validation possible?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i have this javascript validation, is it possible to extract MYSQL data to become a Validator using javascript ?.

```
function validateForm()
        {


          errmsg = '';

          var clientEmail = document.getElementById('clientEmail').value;

          if (clientEmail !== <?php  $sentEmailClients = $row['email'];?>)
          {
            errmsg += "<br />You must enter a valid Client Email";
            }

          return errmsg;
        }
```

Comment: javascript runs in browser and has no way to connect to mysql...can only connect to it using php which runs on server. You can't mix the two the way you are doing. Suggest you study some tutorials on form validtaion

Comment: hmm.. ok thanks got it  :) i'll try a different approach